# if 'a' and 'b' == True will run but not, 'a' and 'b' == False

Tags: python

I was doing some of the questions in CodeBat and came up with a solution for one of the exercises. But one of them does not work

It will work like this:

```
def test(a,b):
    if a and b == True:
        return True

print(test(True, True))
# outputs True
```

But returns None like this:

```
def test(a,b):
    if a and b == False:
        return True

print(test(False, False))
# outputs None
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second function outputs `None` because one of the conditions is not satisfied.
`if a and b == False` is interpreted as `if (a) and (b == False)`. `if a` checks if `a` is considered to have a [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of true. In this case `False` is not a truth value, so if-block is not executed, hence returns `None`.

If you want to test if both are `False`, then:

```
def test(a,b):
    if not a and not b:
        return True

print(test(False, False))
# outputs True
```

or

```
def test(a,b):
    if a == False and b == False:
        return True

print(test(False, False))
# outputs True
```

Answer (score 2):

`a and b == True` aka `(a) and (b == True)` is satisfied if both of these conditions are true:

- `a` is a true value, and
- `b` is equal to `True`.

`a and b == False` aka `(a) and (b == False)` is satisfied if both of these conditions are true:

- `a` is a true value, and
- `b` is equal to `False`.